# How do I inflate an XML ShapeDrawable and also define its position on screen?

Tags: android

I'm totally confused on drawing shapes I define in an XML file and whether I need a view, canvas or shapedrawaable etc etc!

**What I'm Attempting To Achieve**

I want to define several BASIC shapes in XML such as a rectangle and circle including their dimensions and colour. I would also like to define their position on screen.

**My Code So Far**

BasicShapes.java

```
package com.kerry.basicshapes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BasicShapes extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

shapes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#f0600000"/>
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#00FF00"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

How do I get the rectangle I've defined in shapes.xml onto the screen? I can't find any examples of what I want to do and can't get my head around the Android documentation. Can I achieve this in main.xml and how do I stipulate the size and position of the XML defined shape?

Many thanks for your help

Kerubu

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your main.xml in the container that you want to contain it, seems to work for me.

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/generic_window_shape"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Having a similar problem, but this might have helped me too ;)